# How to reference downloaded file to populate listview

Tags: android, listview

I populate a DrawerListView in the following manner:

```
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
           getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dataElements)));
```

The list drawer is properly populated and displays the data as expected.  However, rather than reference the R.array.dataElements I want to reference a file (list.xml) that I downloaded to the ExternalStorageDirectory.  How do I get a resource ID to this downloaded file so I can populate the ListView?

-- UPDATE --

I was able to achieve the desired result with the following code.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

```
try {
        myArray = new ArrayList<String>();

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyApp/list.xml");
        InputStream instream = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(instream));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        // Parse XML file and store in string

        NodeList myNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

        for (int i = 0; i < myNodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node myNode = myNodeList.item(i);
            if(myNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){

                myArray.add(myNode.getTextContent());

            }


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are saving to external storage directory (firstly, don't forget to declare permissions),  you won't be able to reference it as a resource ID, because it is not bundled with your app (it is stored on SD card).

one way is to download the file, but have a middle layer (like a parser) that takes your file (on SD card) and can return a string array, and have your Adapter read that.

see this android listview tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

as for SD card, you can read it like this:

as for reading a file from SD card, just use something like this to get an input stream: File

```
sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

File directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Pictures");

File file = new File(directory, "image_name.jpg"); //or any other format supported

FileInputStream streamIn = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  That link has alot of good code.  However, I  can not seem to find a code example of parsing a xml file located on the sdcard and put it into a string array.

Comment: here's an xml parser documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: the same guy gives a brief intro about xml parsing: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidXML/article.html.